# How do I delete a Windows file with a trailing space, (or period), character?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

How to delete a file with zero byte created accidentally with name "Call" ?

I'm facing with this issue that i couldn't figure it out until now ?

I tried with command `Del` but no chance.

```
@echo off
set "targetdir=C:\FolderDir"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir/s/b/a-d "%targetdir%\*.*"') do ( if %%~Za equ 0 echo %%~na>>results.txt && del "%%~a" )
```

I tried also to remove the directory which contains this file "Call"

```
RD /S /Q [ParentFolder with file Call Inside]
```

---

I tried with Powershell too :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\MyFolderDir" -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Length -eq 0 } | remove-item
```

---

***EDIT :***

I execute this command below provided by @Compo in his comment :

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /T /F "C:\FolderDir":"*call*"
```

And i got as result like this :

```
 ? ? ? "C:\Users\Hackoo\Desktop\Scripting\Call "
```

Comment: Does the file by any chance have an appended or prepended space in the filename?

Comment: Hackoo, are you sure that the filename does not have leading, or much more likely given your issue, trailing, whitespace? Check the result of `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /T /F "C:\FolderDir":"*call*"`.

Comment: @Compo i got something like this as result `         ?         ?       ?          "C:\Users\Hackoo\Desktop\Scripting\Call "`

Comment: As I suspected @Hackoo, your filename has a trailing space, doesn't it? Trailing spaces are not valid in Windows, _(NTFS)_, file and directory names; whilst they can be created, they are, as you've seen problematic to work with. Have you tried to delete it like this: `Del /A /F "\\?\C:\Users\Hackoo\Desktop\Scripting\Call "`?

Comment: @Compo Yes the file is deleted finally ! Thank you  ! Please post it as answer in order to accept it !

Comment: I hope you don't mind @Hackoo, but I've modified your question title to better reflect the issue, and aid future readers with a similar one to locate this question in their searches.

Comment: Similar question: https://superuser.com/q/198256/1077440

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Windows underlying file system does support file or directory names which end with a space or a period, so it is possible to create them. However the Windows Win32 file namespace API functions as used with shell applications do not. In your case, based upon your provided information, I determined that your actual filename was not `Call` but `Call` .

To clarify that there was a trailing whitespace character, I asked you to check your filename using the `where.exe` utility, which using its `/F` option, would display your filepath double-quoted. I additionally included the `/T` option which would confirm the files' size and modified date details.

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /T /F "C:\Users\Hackoo\Desktop\Scripting":"*call*"
```

From your provided clarification, that my assumption was correct, you simply needed a method of deleting the file, bypassing the API's string parsing.

You can read all about Windows rules for files, paths, and namespaces, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

The solution to your problem, as should be noted within the information of the fore-mentioned link, is to use the `\\?\` prefix, to bypass that enforcement.

```sh
Del /A /F "\\?\C:\Users\Hackoo\Desktop\Scripting\Call "
```

In your case, as noted from your file attributes, `-a----`, as shown [in another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67884051/how-to-delete-a-file-with-zero-byte-created-accidentally-with-name-call-on-win?noredirect=1#comment119988438_67884499), you don't really need the `/A` or `/F` options, so the following should be sufficient:

```sh
Del "\\?\C:\Users\Hackoo\Desktop\Scripting\Call "
```

---

And for completeness, you could do the same thing in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\C:\Users\Hackoo\Desktop\Scripting\Call "
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you created the file from git-bash, there it is easy to create a file with trailing spaces.

```
touch "call "
```

And it's also easy to remove it from bash

```
rm "call "
```